# I have installed and configured django-allauth-2fa. How to create a button for user to apply 2fa?

Tags: django, django-authentication, django-allauth, multi-factor-authentication

all. I have installed and configured django-allauth-2fa following this documentation: https://django-allauth-2fa.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation/. Can anyone tell me what to do next to apply to 2fa to the users? Thank you very much in advance.
Alex

I have installed and configured django-allauth-2fa following this documentation: https://django-allauth-2fa.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation/. How to create a button for user to apply 2fa?

Comment: The "I have installed" sentence was duplicated in this question.